# Memory Leak error in Glassfish server 5.0

Tags: java, memory-leaks, application-server, glassfish-5

There is a heap memory error once the glassfish server 5.0 is up and running for 2,3 hours where my application is deployed.
Heap memory dump shows sun.security.ssl.sslengineimpl including "java.static.org.glassfish.grizzly.npn.NegotiationSupport.alpnserverNegotiator" consume 78% of memory.
Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that there was a memory leak in glassfish on Usage of HTTP/2 (default) leads to a memory leak.What I really did is disable http2 in every listeners.

**asadmin >set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.http2-enabled=false

asadmin >set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.http2-enabled=false

asadmin >set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.admin-listener.http.http2-enabled=false**

and change the **DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER** of Grizzly in glassfish too.

***-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER= org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager***